# Is it possible to target a specific path in svg that has the fill attribute setted using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Good day all, I've a page in which I inject some svg elements, they look like this:

```
<svg>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d='....'></path>
<path d='....'></path>
<path d='....'></path>
<path d='....'></path>
</svg>
```

I cannot alter the svg files that are injected using a javascript library, and I'd like to change their background color on the fly, is there a way to target the only path that has the fill attribute setted to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can use hasAttribute whether element have a particular or not

```
document.querySelectorAll('.svg path').map( o=> 
        if(!o.hasAttribute('fill')) {
            o.setAttribute('fill', '#eee')
        } 
    );
```